# git-flow & gerrit: editing on the release branch

Tags: git, gerrit, git-flow

I'm using this fork of git-flow https://github.com/RasmusVoss/gitflow (exactly https://github.com/m42e/gitflow which I adapted to the REST api of gerrit).

My question is, how to handle changes in a release branch? Should everyone who has to do last minute changes a feature branch, based on the release branch? Will that work? Is that supported or recomended?

Or should all work directly on the release branch and submit all changes as review to gerrit?
Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot.
Bye,
m42e

Answer (score 1):

All should work on the release branch and push their changes to review.